# ORA-01861 literal does not match format string on SELECT statement

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlexception

Good day.

I am executing a query and encountering:

```
ORA-01861 literal does not match format string error.
```

I executed this query and IT WORKED.

```
SELECT * FROM GCACC_OPERATION_DETAIL WHERE id_notice in (75078741) 
AND id_analytical_center in (100000002) 
AND interface_date = '2013-06-30' 
AND generic_client = 'someGenClient' 
AND document_class = 'DOCCLA0001' 
AND accounting_tag_identifier = 1 
AND generated_actual_acc_doc 
IN (select id_accounting_document 
from gcacc_accounting_document 
where document_status = 'DOCSTA0001');
```

My other query is written below which DID NOT WORK.

```
SELECT * FROM GCACC_OPERATION_DETAIL WHERE id_notice IN (75078741) 
AND id_analytical_center in (100000002) 
AND generic_client = 'someGenClient' 
AND document_class = 'DOCCLA0001' 
AND accounting_tag_identifier = 1 
AND interface_date = '2013-06-30' 
AND ind_pending_process = 1 
AND operation_type 
IN (select cod_develop from gcacc_operation_type where ind_operation = 'B');
```

This is really weird because the error happens in the date part but I am writing the same syntax for the date part. I maybe missing something silly here and fresher eyes are needed. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what the specific problem is, but assuming "interface_date" is a DATE type, it is bad practice to use literals in a query for a date.  This makes the assumption that the default NLS_DATE_FORMAT agrees with your date literal.  That will come back to bite you.  To ensure that your date constraint is portable, change to this:

```
AND interface_date = to_date('2013-06-30','YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. I investigated further and got the reason why this is happening. The first query does not have a result set while the second has that is why the first query doesn't throw an error. Thanks for your good practice about sql dates I will implement that! :)

Comment: Hi do you have a list of date formats which I could supply for the 2nd parameter of to_date() ? thanks. :)

Comment: Here's all the oracle formatting options - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm

Comment: It's bad to use *string* literals for dates, especially with implicit conversion.  But it's a good idea to use an ANSI date literal.  Change it to `date '2013-06-30'` and it will work regardless of the NLS_DATE_FORMAT, and it will also be checked at compile time instead of run time.